# Project is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm trying to connect my MVC Core project
to my library(Universal Windows Platform) with the SqlLite but i am getting the following compilation error:

```
Project ChatProj is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). 
Project ChatProj supports: uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063)  WebChat C:\Users\VadimPc\source\repos\ChatProj\WebChat\WebChat.csproj   1
```

Comment: I assume the other project is not a .NET Core but a Universal Windows Platform project?

Comment: Yes the library is Universal Windows Platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically .NET Core projects can only reference .NET Standard or other .NET Core projects, thus referencing Universal Windows Platform projects is not possible. This is not entirely true however, a .NET Core project could for instance reference a .NET Framework library using compatibility shims. I suspect your UWP project also contains a user interface, in which case extracting the logic to a .NET Standard project and referencing the new library would make sense, while leaving the GUI in the UWP project.

Comment: So how do i combine  UWP and MVC project?

Comment: As a first step I recommend reading some background information about .NET runtimes and supported platforms, .NET Core and .NET Standard. As second step I would separate the user interface and logic in the UWP-project by splitting them into two separate projects.

Comment: I did separate them into 2 different projects, I had one library for database proj and the 2 GUI projects, MVC and Windows 10